# using eclipse's proxy settings for maven's dependency solving

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using eclipse (Springsource toolsuite) and I'm behind a proxy. In eclipse I configured my proxy (ip, username, password) so I can download plugins. Now for maven I also have specify these proxy settings in a settings.xml duplicating the proxy params and exposing my password. Is there a way to get maven use the eclipse proxy settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Eclipse an Maven work separately.

Your user-level settings for Maven need to be in a settings.xml as Khmarbaise suggested, and you have to place it in a .m2 folder in c:/users/[name]/ directory on Windows 7, or /home directory in linux.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>server001</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

See this page for details: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer no, cause Maven uses it's own downloading etc. So no way... Your settings should be located in your home directory which is protected by your personal passwords...so this shouldn't be a problem.